# Rule of Three with different origin

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that this may by a very newbie question but I am really struggling with it.

If I have 2 dimensions that are directly proportial I can use a rule of three to transform from one magnitud to another. But what if each dimension has a different origin?

Example:

```
1 is a 3
as 5 is a 10
as 3 is a X
```

How can I calculate X?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are overthinking this. It's just multiplying by two (most likely)

Comment: @DonThousand yes, my original example was not good, I changed it to represent better my situation

Comment: It seems as though you are only dealing with linear relationships. In that case, what I would do is set up an equation $y=mx+b$, and plug in $(1,2)$ and $(5,10)$ into $(x,y)$ to form two separate equations in terms of $m,b$, and solve for $m,b$. Then, take the new $x$, and plug it into the equation to compute $y$, your desired value.

Comment: @DonThousand I added a solution following can you check if this is compatible with your proposition?

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[image]

```
(b - a) is a (d - c)
as (e - a) is a (x - c)
```

Then I apply the rule of three:

```
(e - a)(d - c)
-------------- = x - c
   (b - a)
```

Or:

```
    (e - a)(d - c)
c + -------------- = x
        (b - a)
```

Applying this to our example we have

```
    (3 - 1)(10 - 3)
3 + -------------- = x
        (5 - 1)

x = 6.5
```

Which looks valid

Can someone confirm my reasoning is valid? and if I can simplify the above formula?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: You don'r need a lot of algebra nor the formal "rule of three" for this particular problem. On the top line $e$ is the midpoint of $ab$ so $x$ must be the corresponding midpoint on the bottom line. That's at $6.5$.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, for my example this is enough but I am looking for a generic solution. For any `e`

Comment: I think your algebra is right. You find out the fraction $ea/ba$ and then apply that fraction to $dc$ to find $xc$.